# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle, toad

IN Toad 9,while executing 'SET DEFINE OFF;' I am getting error as 'ORA-00922: missing or invalid option'

Comment: The `SET DEFINE [ON|OFF]` command is specific to SQL*Plus; it's processed by the SQL*Plus client, it's not sent to the database. That statement is not a valid Oracle SQL statement. Some SQL*Plus commands are accepted and honored by TOAD if you run the statements as a script; I've used SQL*Plus style commands for column formatting, but I've not tested the `SET DEFINE` command though.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can do this:

Navigate to `View` > `TOAD Options` >  And go to `"execute/compile" node/item` and uncheck the `Prompt for substitution variables` option.

Or, for editor level change, Right click in the editor and uncheck `Prompt for substitution variables`

Comment: SET DEFINE OFF works for scripts. If you are executing a single statement using F9 you need to follow Pam's advice. It's solid.